# Where can i see received SMS that I sent from Facebook?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp-cloud-api, twiliosms

I can't find where it sent the SMS to and how can I get the verification code from Twilio, any help?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you go to `Monitor`->`Logs`->`Messaging`, you should be able to see (and filter) the messages being sent to/from your Twilio account, including the numbers messages are sent to (and from.)

Comment: I tried it keeps showing "There are no incoming Message Logs for this phone number."
although i sent the sms verification multiple times

Comment: also "We could not find any logs for your account."

Comment: Is this a code question? If so, is a Message SID being printed out?  Is the verification code from Twilio to your personal phone #?

Comment: Its not code question, no im just trying to verifiy Twilio with my facebook page but i cannot recieve any sms verification.